# Charlotte potato discolouration

Tags: potatoes

Just dug up my first harvest of Charlotte potatoes. The plants look nice and healthy, but the tubers all had this faint internal discolouration. Any idea what it might be?

They cooked and tasted fine. This might be a coincidence, but I've noticed a similar discolouration in shop-bought potatoes in recent weeks. I live in Essex, UK.

[image]

Comment: Probably something seasonal, not sure

Comment: Is the inner, darker part softer? Or is it only a change of color?